# Ansible - how to use ternary function with lineinfile module?

Tags: linux, ansible, jinja2

We have requirement to add line if it is not in that file on basis of hostname.

It means:

- if hostname is `abc` then line `"ABC"` goes to `/etc/app.conf`
- otherwise line `"XYZ"` goes to `/etc/app.conf` file.

What would be better approach for this?
Do we use jinja2 template or define logic in playbook?
Please suggest on both.

Comment: That's not how StackOverflow works: we don't write code for you, but we are happy to help you solve specific technical problems.  Show us what you've tried so far, and make it clear where you are having problems.  Are there errors? Are there parts of the documentation that are unclear?

Comment: Thanks larsks,  i wanted to use ternary filter with lineinfile module, but unable to make it and got syntax related issues.

Answer (score 4):

It's really a matter of preference and what you want to log in the output. I guess for such an easy task using the following would be easiest:

```
- name: Ensure line ABC is configured for host ABC
  lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/abc.conf
    line: "ABC"
  when: inventory_hostname == "abc"

- name: Ensure line XYZ is configured for hosts other than ABC
  lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/abc.conf
    line: "XYZ"
  when: inventory_hostname != "abc"
```

Or use the ternary filter in one task:

```
- lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/abc.conf
    line: "{{ ( inventory_hostname == 'abc' ) | ternary ('ABC','XYZ') }}"
```

If the configuration file required more changes or you'd want to ensure the configuration is exactly as you want, a template file would be a better fit.

Comment: thnaks techrf, is there any way to use ternary filter with lineinfile ?